# IBOutlet and lifetime qualifier in ARC

Tags: cocoa-touch, automatic-ref-counting

The template  "MasterDetail" application writes an `IBOutlet` property in DetailViewController.h with `strong` qualifier.

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *detailDescriptionLabel;
```

While in Standford CS193 lessons from iTunesU (lesson 2 time 14:30) they set an `IBOutlet` as `weak` saying the label already has a strong pointer to it created by window.

Now, my question is how we have to declare storage for IBOutlet like Label and Button ? is it correct to use weak ? and if i'm on iOS4 is it ok use unsafe_unretained ?

EDIT-----

I found answer about strong or weak ... the main rules are :

- Use `strong` for top level elements of the xib
- Use `weak` for subelements like label buttons etc..

You can check [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/LoadingResources/CocoaNibs/CocoaNibs.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000051i-CH4-SW6)
But i still can't find something about iOS 4

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, it's basically the same case as in MRC.

Your IBOutlets are usually inside your controller's view hierarchy and implicitly retained by their parent views. You can use `assign` (MRC) or `weak` or `unsafe_unretained` (ARC). In all cases your pointer is invalidated when you remove the object from your view hierarchy.
The only difference is that on MRC and ARC 4.0 the pointer is not set automatically to nil. It still contains a memory address but the address is invalid.
In any case, you shouldn't use the pointer any more.

Whenever you want to use the object even if it's not a part of your view hierarchy (usually every top level element in xib or when you are removing views from your hierarchy dynamically and you do not want them to be invalidated), you use `retain` or `strong` specifiers.

Note that many examples use `strong` for every IBOutlets and it's not an error. It's just not necessary.